# Eigen Library - Pseudo-Inverse of Matrix (Matlab - pinv)

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, eigen

I am trying to find the pseudo-inverse of a matrix using the Eigen Library. They have a class that does implement it, however I do not know how to put script the syntax.

This is how it is shown on the website (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition.html#ab2fd4c81aa1cd8bc917c7f135505cb7f):

const Inverse Eigen::CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition< MatrixType >::pseudoInverse  (       )   const

Comment: And what *exactly* is your problem? Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] as well as a clear problem statement.

Answer (score 12):

It's a method of the `CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition` class. So you have to perform that decomposition of a matrix before you use it. For example

```
#include <Eigen/QR>    

Eigen::MatrixXd A = ... // fill in A
Eigen::MatrixXd pinv = A.completeOrthogonalDecomposition().pseudoInverse();
```

Comment: Though it's recommended to use other solvers in most cases.

Comment: Yes, definitely

Comment: @AdiShavit Why is it recommended to use other solvers?

Comment: @AdiShavit, could you give references? Which solvers would you recommend?

Comment: @ignacio: Eigen docs say not to use it (not efficient or numerically stable:  see https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition.html#a3c89639299720ce089435d26d6822d6f).  See https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__LeastSquares.html for better suggestions for solving linear systems in Eigen.

Comment: Result of A.completeOrthogonalDecomposition().pseudoInverse() and MATLAB pinv() are not the same. Please refer to https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/2462 for more detail information.