# Why do I get the wrong answer when using eigen3 to inverse matrix

Tags: c++, eigen3

I'm using eigen3 to  take the inverse of the matrix,but the inverse is wrong.
I tried several examples,but the following this is wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;
int main(){
    Matrix3d Mat1;
Mat1 << 99.999999999999972 ,-29024.672261149386 ,29024.848775176863,-29024.672261149386, 8629880.2300641891 ,-8629930.2299046051,29024.848775176863,-8629930.2299046051 , 8629980.2300641891 ;
cout << "Mat1=\n" << Mat1 << endl;
   Matrix3d Mat2=Mat1.inverse();
cout << "Mat1逆矩阵：\n" << Mat2 << endl;
cout << "Mat1*Mat2：\n" << Mat1*Mat2 << endl;
cout << "Mat2*Mat1：\n" << Mat2*Mat1 << endl;
cout << "Mat1行列式：\n" << Mat1.determinant() << endl;

the result is:
Mat1=
         100     -29024.7      29024.8
    -29024.7  8.62988e+06 -8.62993e+06
     29024.8 -8.62993e+06  8.62998e+06
Mat1逆矩阵：
    44.3313    -12557.7    -12557.8
   -12557.7 3.58199e+06 3.58201e+06
   -12557.8 3.58201e+06 3.58204e+06
Mat1*Mat2：
           1 -0.000198364  0.000823975
    -80.0958     0.785156    -0.242188
     80.0963   -0.0634151     0.972687
Mat2*Mat1：
           1     -80.0958      80.0963
-0.000198364     0.785156      -0.0625
 0.000818345    -0.243301     0.972687
Mat1行列式：
5.73875
```

Shouldn't mat1*mat2 be a unit matrix?

Comment: Maybe your matrix is not invertible, or you're running into precision issues.

Comment: The determinant is not a good indicator for how well conditioned a matrix is. The last two rows (or cols) of `Mat1` are almost opposite to each other, which is a sign for being poorly conditioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using pseudo-inverse instead. That problem maybe a precision issues as @paddy said.

Got that code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44465197/eigen-library-pseudo-inverse-of-matrix-matlab-pinv)

```
#include <Eigen/QR>    
Eigen::MatrixXd A = ... // fill in A
Eigen::MatrixXd pinv = A.completeOrthogonalDecomposition().pseudoInverse();
```

My result:

```
Mat3*Mat1：
       1  3.05176e-05 -3.05176e-05
       0            1   -0.0078125
 2.88524e-05   -0.0137121      1.00454
Mat1*Mat3：
 1.00004   -0.0101929   -0.0101624
-3.05176e-05      1.00781            0
 5.83113e-05   -0.0134087     0.996313
```

Comment: the determinant is not 0，so it should be invertible.when I use pseudo-inverse instead as @ignacio said, I got a entirely different answer .the new matrix mul the original matrix got a unit matrix. which result is right?What does precision issues mean exactly?would you explain it ?@paddy

Comment: @donglou floating point cannot represent just any value.. when you multiply  large value on very small ones you'll get an unstable result which is quite different from strict mathematical one. Direct canonical method of inversion gets imprecise for a matrix where those operations happen. Firstly determinant itself would be imprecise, because, let say, well take a value from first row and multiply it by determinant of 2x2 matrix from lower row, Next you'll have to divide by that imprecise value and so on..

Comment: @Swift - Friday Pie,I got it,thanks.By definition,using pseudo-inverse got a right result.does that mean I should choose it? if the matrix value is random number,which method should I choose?

Comment: Pseudo-inverse equation is an approximation of the inverse, it is also used for least square. So the result you are getting is the "closest" one to the analytical inverse.

Comment: @donglou the fact that inversion is used on random matrix is suspicious per se. One critea which can be used can be absolute value of determinant. If it is below certain epsion or is very high, then analitycal inversion may provide less precise result than approximation. But much better situation is when martix got some physical or geometrical meaning. E.g. if it's matrix of isotropic  space transform, it might be converted into pair of scaling matrix and matrix of cosines, the latter is well-defined by its properties, determinant non-zero and all colums having magnitude of 1.